# Необязательный пункт. Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, общие-вопросы, выбор-слов, частица-не

Как правильно написать? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны разные варианты:

**Слитно:**

Я специально предусмотрел этот необязательный пункт. Это ― совершенно необязательный пункт.

**Раздельно:**

Не обязательный пункт, но очень приятный. 
Это возможный, но совсем не обязательный пункт. 
Это не обязательный пункт, а всего лишь желательный.

Comment: При раздельном написании всегда присутствует противопоставление слову "обязательный". "Не обязательный, НО...".

Comment: Необязательный пункт, но очень приятный - пишем слитно, нет противопоставления. По типу: неглубокая. но рыбная.

Comment: Обрыв невысокий, но крутой. Роль небольшая, но яркая. Но: Дорога предстояла приятная,  но не близкая. Классика жанра: в первой части НЕ пишется слитно, а во второй раздельно. Хотя эти варианты решения  орфограммы встречаются чаще, они не являются обязательными, так как в предложениях с сопоставлением используется смысловое (авторское) решение , которое может отличаться от формального, например: Он не мрачен, но серьезен и задумчив. Пример составлен по образцу: "Не обязательный факт, но очень приятный. [Женщина + мужчина: Психология любви (форум) (2004)] .

Comment: >>  *используется смысловое (авторское) решение , которое может отличаться от формального, например: Он не мрачен, но серьезен и задумчив* Просто нет такого слова – "немрачный", "немрачен".

Comment: Не так важно, есть или нет такое слово, важно, что в первой части предложения может использоваться отрицание. И опять же об ударении: (1) Необязательный пУнкт, но очень приятный. - (2) Не обязАтельный пункт, но очень приЯтный. При отрицании ударение падает на прилагательное,  и ударением подчеркивается однородность именной части сказуемого. Сравним: Обрыв невысОкий, но крутОй. Тогда нужно перестроить заданное предложение: Пункт необязАтельный, но приЯтный. Вот здесь слитное написание. Да и в правилах говорится о том, что раздельное написание НЕ обычно встречается в начале предложения.